# Yelp API - Too Many Request Per Second in Node.js

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, yelp

Experts,

It seems that yelp recently changed their REST API to limit the amount of requests you can make per second.  I've tried using setTimeout and various sleep functions with no success.  I believe it has to do with setTimeout although.  I only get a few responses back and a slew of TOO_Many_Requests_Per_Second.  Also, I'm using the Node.js Fusion API Client.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here is the code below as I'm getting the Yelp URL from my Parse Server, and I want to get the Yelp Business Name response:

```
'use strict';

var Parse = require('parse/node');

Parse.initialize("ServerName");
Parse.serverURL = 'ParseServerURL';
const yelp = require('yelp-fusion');
const client = yelp.client('Key');

var object;
var Business = Parse.Object.extend("Business");
var query = new Parse.Query(Business);

query.notEqualTo("YelpURL", "Bus");

query.find({
success: function(results) {

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    object = results[i];
    //I belive a setTimeout block needs to come somewhere in here.  Tried many places but with no success.
    client.business(object.get('YelpURL')).then(response => {
     console.log(response.jsonBody.name);

    }).catch(e => {
     console.log(e);
    });
   }
  },

  error: function(error) {
   alert("Error" + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query each, which will iterate over each object and perform the requests in a sequence rather than all more or less at once:

```
query.each(
    function(object) {
        return client.business(object.get('YelpURL')).then(response => {
            console.log(response.jsonBody.name);
        });
    }
).catch( e => {
    res.json('error');
});
```

One cool thing about this is that it'll automatically propagate the error from `client.bussiness()` call if there is one to the catch block at the bottom.  It will iterate over the objects one at a time, and since we "return" the results of the `client.business()` call, it's not going to move on to the next object until you've gotten the response.  `query.each()` will also iterate over every object in a collection that meets your query criteria, so you don't have to worry about limits.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, if you could :)

Comment: Oh I'll add that you could also add a catch block directly to `client.business()` still, so you can handle the individual errors, as right now it's going to end the whole function from the first error. You could leave it empty if you don't want to do anything, just to make sure the iteration continues.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if this is what your looking for, but you can retrieve up to 50 records per request, in the example below will return 20 business names within that zip code, or you can tweak it a little to return all that data for those businesses, does this help:

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  let zipcode = req.params.id;
  let names = [];
  let searchRequest = {
    term: 'Business', // or for ex. food
    limit: 20, //set the number of responses you want up to 50
    radius: 20000, // 20 miles
    location: zipcode
  };
    client.search(searchRequest)
    .then(response => {
      response.jsonBody.businesses.map(elem => {
        names.push(elem.name);
      })
      res.json(names); // business names only
      //or
      //res.json(response.jsonBody.businesses) //all details included with business name    
    }).catch(e => {
      res.json('error');
    });
})
```